# Redirecting a web page to a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the page http://www.unived.in/ to http://www.unived.in/aboutus/.
I tried lots of plugins but the page still isn't redirected. In fact I have tried changing .htaccess but it still doesn't redirect properly. Sometimes it displays error 500.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond /home/unived/public_html/wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule \.xml(\.gz)?$ /wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What do I need to do to make the redirection work?

Comment: I really don't know what exactly is it? But I think yes

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial to learn more about mod_rewrite: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/mod-rewrite-syntax.php

It's very detailed, and should help you accomplish your goal.

Comment: You shouldn't post links to tutorials. You should post the explanation here, possibly including a source.